# Wordpress polylang with polylang slug plugin lang switch not working

Tags: php, wordpress, multilingual, slug, language-switching

For a current Wordpress project we used the polylang plugin. But because we had to have the same slug for all languages we also used the polylang slug plugin.

Example:

www.yourdomein.com/nl/my-slug

www.yourdomein.com/en/my-slug

Everything went well, the url's where working we can have the same slug for all languages. Except the fact that the language switch on our page suddenly always links to the current language.

Example:

current language = nl

language switch has the following links:

nl => www.yourdomein.com/nl/my-slug

en => www.yourdomein.com/**nl**/my-slug

Does somebody has a solution for this of has experienced something similar?

Thanks in advance,
Joren

Comment: Have you fixed this issue?

Comment: @chithra I haven't